# Get outer border of regions USA

Tags: google-maps, kml

In USA, I'm looking for outline of the Division 9 Pacific which consists of the following states:

- Alaska
- California
- Hawaii
- Oregon
- Washington

I have got a map with the KML to generate for these states: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lYAaPc-U3sv6hUlbhBsQJ0vzXfw&usp=sharing

But I just want the outline of the whole area and NOT the state borders. How can I get this?

Comment: Region 9 of what? The organization with regions may have a GIS file for their regions. e.g. EPA Regions: https://www.epa.gov/enviro/geospatial-data-download-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done by using a GIS software like ArcGIS.

First you convert the kml file to a layer, then you dissolve the borders and then export a new layer to a kml file which would look something like this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pc2l4s2hkcsbrz5/Pacific%20Region.kml